# Generate Html List in Snap

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I want to integrate Snap's templating and Blaze HTML builder by building some HTML and binding it to a tag for use in a Heist template. Here is what I have attempted.

```
numbers :: Int -> Splice AppHandler
numbers n = return $ [TextNode $ T.concat.toChunks.renderHtml $ do
                    p "A list of natural numbers"
                    ul $ forM_ [1 .. n] (li .toHtml)]
```

This does not work as intended since snap renders the HTML string directly to the generated page. How do I get snap to render blaze generated HTML?

Comment: It looks like your comment is really about integrating blaze-html into the Heist library, so that's the answer I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with a Heist splice, the function `renderHtmlNodes` from the `Text.Blaze.Renderer.XmlHtml` module in the *xmlhtml* package should help a lot in this case.

Docs: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmlhtml/0.1.5.2/doc/html/Text-Blaze-Renderer-XmlHtml.html

I don't fully understand your example, but this is how I would modify it to incorporate my suggestion:

```
numbers :: Int -> Splice AppHandler
numbers n = return $ renderHtmlNodes $ do
                    p "A list of natural numbers"
                    ul $ forM_ [1 .. n] (li .toHtml)
```

Comment: If you can take his example and use `renderHtmlNodes` to do the same thing, this answer would be much clearer.

Comment: Great, I was looking someplace else entirely, namely the Heist docs and I aslo checked snap-blaze to no avail. Thank you.